# Does deleting unused files such as images, javascript, xml, html, asp etc make your Windows Server faster?

Tags: performance-tuning

I have an IIS7 Windows 2003 Dedicated server.

I just wanted to know if I delete old files such as

XML, HTML, ASP, PHP, images, CSS, JavaScript.. etc.. files that are no longer used..

Does this make my server faster?

Answer (score 4):

If you're low on disk space yes but otherwise no, no it doesn't.

Comment: What Chopper3 said, there really isn't much to gain unless your disk is below 10% free space - even then the gains can be marginal

Answer (score 0):

**If nothing is operating on those files then, No.** Extra files don't slow the server.

**If any of the below are true then, Yes.** You may see some performance improvement by removing them.

- **If they are accessible via the web:**
  then web crawlers will hit them.
- **If they are often changed:**
  then windows search indexing will index them.
- **If they take up your last GB of disk space:**
  then they may interfere with disk access & fragmentation.
- **If you browse to the folder containing the files:**
  then they will cause extra GUI load to look up and display the metedata.